# ob_start + compress breaks served file outputs

Tags: php

I am working in a MVC pattern situation here.

I have `index.php` as a base file, controllers located in `/controllers/` directory. If you go to `/stream/xIEjeEJWqs` for example `/controllers/streamcontroller.php` will be executed.

`index.php` starts like this and it minifies an output that is about to be sent to browser:

```
<?php

function replace_tabs_newlines($content)
{
    require_once 'includes/min/lib/Minify/HTML.php';
    require_once 'includes/min/lib/Minify/CSS_MODIFIED.php';
    require_once 'includes/min/lib/JSMin.php';
    $content = Minify_HTML::minify($content, array(
        'cssMinifier' => array('Minify_CSS', 'minify'),
        'jsMinifier' => array('JSMin', 'minify')
    ));
    return $content;
}

ob_start('replace_tabs_newlines');
ob_implicit_flush(0);
...
```

So this code minfies whatever is being outputted, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Minifies..
        </title>
```

becomes `<html><head><title>Minifies..</title>`

So, problem is that streamcontroller.php has to output something as PNG, MP4, and other and when it `readfile()`-s a content, browser cannot recognize a content which is compressed by `index.php` in the beginning.

Extract from streamcontroller.php:

```
case "png":
  header('Content-type:image/png');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));     
  readfile($file);
  exit;
break;
```

Now my questions are following:

1. What would you recommend, taking out `streamcontroller.php` from MVC? Having `streamer.php` next to `index.php` for example?
2. Adding check functionanility in `index.php`'s `replace_tabs_newlines($content)` function to check if browser is pointing at `streamcontroller.php` and do not do a minify job?
3. Maybe there is a way to stop `ob_start()`'s callback from being exacuted while being about to output something? ie: before `readfile()` in `streamcontroller.php`?
4. I will appreciate new ideas that are quite accepted in situations like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an [`ob_end_clean`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) before the `readfile`

Comment: yes, it works well. like this: `ob_end_clean(); header('Content-type:image/png'); header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); readfile($file);exit;`... It's just i'm not sure if this is a good approach of doing it, please tell me if there are any drawbacks and I'll gladly accept your answer. thank you

Comment: @tmpmember I see no drawbacks to this approach